Can we have MathJax?
It would have been so much easier for me to write this answer if Music SE had access to MathJax, like several other SE sites do. In our Meta, I found a question from 2019, where a commenter quoted timing tests from 2013 as an argument against MathJax. I wonder if something improved since 11 years ago?
If someone wonders if we even need math notation on Music SE: we do. We ask and answer questions about construction of musical instruments, psychoacoustics, electronic instruments and signal processors, amplifiers and digital audio processing. Math is often the most appropriate language to talk about these topics.

I think from previous discussion, that we cannot have that as well as the ABC.js running together. I can't find the posts i think it was discussed in, though, so ust leaving this as a comment.

@DoktorMayhem uh, personally I would prefer MathJax which works very well, rather than ABC.js has many issues on SE...

You may prefer it, but the community looked at various options, and that was by far the preferred tool.

I agree that it would be nice to have MathJax, but for [main], if it's a choice between supporting music notation and mathematical notation, there's no question that music notation is far more pertinent.

@phoog These two separate things: 1. I see a benefits of adding MathJax to this site, 2. the number of issues with ABC implementation on SE makes it cause more trouble than it helps. The conflict between MathJax and ABC was unknown to me when I was asking the question. Of course it would be great to have a good quality music notation system, but in its current state I would see more benefits in MathJax.

Even though I have a degree in mathematics and know LaTeX decently, I've never wanted to use MathJax on MP&T. I wouldn't oppose it if there were no negative consequences to supporting it, but I agree with phoog that ABC.js is much more important, regardless of its flaws (and MathJax isn't perfect either).

@ToddWilcox this discussion is going in an unexpected direction. Something to consider (not necessarily in this comment section): as far as I can see, use of MathJax is very strongly encouraged for math expressions (vs e.g. handwriting or screenshots) on Math SE and some other SE sites. Are we going to demand users to use ABC.js on Music SE? If yes or no, why? Are the reasons similar to the reasons for use of MathJax on Math SE?
